# how to read items from string-array on android

Tags: android, arrays

I got a problem with reading items from string-array one by one. For example, i got string-array with 10 items:

```
<string-array name="arr">
    <item>First</item>
    <item>Second</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>Tenth</item>
</string-array>
```

So i know how to display items randomly, im using this code

```
Resources res = getResources();

myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.arr);

int length=myString.length;
int index=rgenerator.nextInt(length);
String q = myString[index];

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText(q);
```

And in TextView on every button click it displays random item from array.

Problem is, how to make display item from string-array not randomly. Like, it starts from displaying First, then on click it displays Second, and so on untill end of array.
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a variable

```
int currentIndex=0;
```

outside this `onClick` method.

In the

```
onClick(View v)
{
//Verify if only that btn is clicked
{
tv.setText(myString[(currentIndex++)%(myString.length)]);
}
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you, man! it worked! 
My mistake was my counter was inside onClick method..
Thanks again!

Comment: It will crash after n clicks with `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (n = array.lenght). Change `tv.setText(myString[currentIndex++]);` to `tv.setText(myString[currentIndex++ % myString.length]);`

Answer (score 4):

You can't initialize your `testArray` field this way, because the application resources still aren't ready.
Change the code to:

```
package com.xtensivearts.episode.seven;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Episode7 extends ListActivity {
String[] mTestArray;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter that will contain all list items
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    mTestArray =  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);    

    /* Assign the name array to that adapter and 
    also choose a simple layout for the list items */ 
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    mTestArray);

    // Assign the adapter to this ListActivity
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**try**

```
int i=0;
String q = myString[i];
i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="month">
    <item>Jan</item>
    <item>Feb</item>
    <item>Mar</item>
    <item>Apr</item>
    <item>May</item>
    <item>Jun</item>
    <item>Jul</item>
    <item>Aug</item>
    <item>Sep</item>
    <item>Oct</item>
    <item>Nov</item>
    <item>Dec</item>
</string-array>
```

java

```
for (int i = 0; i < getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month).length; i++) {
    Log.e("Array",""+getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month)[i]);
}
```