# Access string values in Model Class

Tags: android, arrays, string, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I want to access string values in model class and then I will pass these values to adapter but it shows error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

```
public static List<CardModel> getObjectList() {

   List<CardModel> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
   int[] images = getImages();
   String[] desc = getdesc();
   //String [] desc = mcontext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);

   for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      CardModel nature = new CardModel();
      nature.setImgid(images[i]);
      nature.setTitle("Rabbana " + i);
      nature.setTvdesc(desc[i]);
      dataList.add(nature);
   }
   return dataList;
}



private static String[] getdesc() {
   Resources res =mcontext.getResources();
   String [] desc = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);
   return desc;
}
```

Comment: You can try directly writing this --> `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);` instead of `mcontext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);`

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834537/how-to-read-items-from-string-array-on-android). Maybe this helps you

Comment: if i do this then resources error occur...cannot resolve symbol getResourse().@MashukKhan

Comment: [Lets continue this in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188729/access-string-values-issue)

Comment: still same issue..@MashukKhan

Comment: i am new on stackoverflow so i have no acces to chat right now.@MashukKhan

Comment: now try to access

Comment: still.. You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.@MashukKhan

Comment: what is `mcontext` ?

Comment: it is parameter in my adapter calass.public static Context mcontext;
    public RecycleAdapter(Context context, List<CardModel> objectList) {
        this.mcontext=context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
        this.objectList = objectList;
        }@MashukKhan

Comment: its a parameter in adapter..@JohnJoe

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable mcontext , I guess it is null which is causing the crash.

Solution- Pass the context in the constructor of the adapter and use it to get resources like below

```
 public TestAdapter( Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

Comment: i'm using the same method. @Shivam Yadav

Comment: @misbahkhan, probably the context which you are sending in the adapter is not valid. If it is fragment then check if fragment is added or not .

Comment: solved my problem...i passed the context in main activity..@Shivam Yadav

Comment: i'm using the context in model class and i want to access throuh adapter..this was a issue beacuse it returns null value when i acces it in model class . @Shivam Yadav

Comment: Great. @misbahkhan